# Incomplete expression in ggaluvial plot

Tags: r, ggalluvial

I want to make an alluvial plot for presence of Antioxidant and No antioxidant vs gene hit(which has three categories, positive hit, negative hit and no hit)
I wrote the following code for that but it gives me an error of incomplete expression
Now I am not sure what might be the problem

This is the code that I am trying to run
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5ytx.png)

My data set

[My Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beJqN.png)

I want an alluvial plot for

AO Present and Hit Class as my two axis or not sure I am even confused for whether to use hit or hit class as the second axis and what to about y

Comment: Dhurvraj, welcome to SO. Please include some example data, a clear description of how you want this figure to look when the code works, and the actual error message you're running into. Right now, it's hard to know what problem you might be having.

Comment: thank you will try that

Comment: First problem: pictures of code. Absolutely the worst communication strategy when asking for coding advice. Second problem, maybe, but unable to test because of "first problem"? You are using a mixture of R symbols and character values in your `aes` arguments. I'm not sure `aes` is built to hand that diversity in argument type.